# Plugin based on call i want to hide

Tags: java, plugins

I want to give my project the possibility to be extendible through a plugin. For the users of that interface I want to create a separate small jar (plugin.jar) file, exposing everything that is needed to write a plugin.

The plugin should only implement one Method `double Calculate (double)`.  For this I could just expose an Interface. But I also want the plugin to be able to call some function `double getParameter(string)`

And now it becomes tricky (at least for me). The actual implementation of `getParameter` depends on some other jars, that I don’t want to reference in plugin.jar. (for cleanness reasons, nothing more) So I can’t provide some kind of PluginBase class for my users to expend.

The best solution I’ve come up with is some kind of combination of using a pImpl Idiom and an additional Interface:

I expose an abstract base class that implements `final getParameter` by calling it on an Object with an interface just containing `getParameter`. This object is passed when creating the plugin in my application as the implementation of that `getParameter` function. However, this means this PluginBase class needs an `setImplementation` function.

User Side:

```
class UserPlugin extends PluginBase
{
   @Override
    public double Calculate(double input)
    {
       return input + this.getDoubleInput("X") + this.getDoubleInput("Y");
    }
}
```

Jar to provide Plugin Interfaces and class

```
public interface IHasInputParameters { Double getParameter(String s) } 

public class PluginBase  implements IHasInputParameters 
{
   private IHasInputParameters impl;
   public abstract double Calculate(double input)

   @Override
   public final Double getParameter(String s) { return impl.getParameter(s));}

   public final void SetImplementation(IHasInputParameters i) { this.impl = i;}     
}
```

Internal Side

```
class PluginImpl  implements IHasInputParameters 
{
   @Override
   public final Double getParameter(String s) 
   {  //// do stuff that depends on stuff I don't want to expose}
}
```

This basicly works. But has to problems.

1. My user could call SetImplemenation and break something. (I could check, that is only called by me on construction and has no effect after that)
2. Initialization of the plugin is awkward. The plugin needs its implementation to call getParameter but the Implementation needs the plugin to call Calculate.

   ```
   PluginImpl implementation = new PluginImpl ();
   Plugin plugin = new Plugin();
   plugin.setImplementation(implementation);
   implementation.SetImplementation(plugin);
   ```

Is there an easier/safer way to do this?

Comment: Post **code** not **pictures**. This is not legible.

Comment: Picture is not meant to read the code but show where what class goes.

Comment: The pictures are badly scaled, aliased, text. They serve no purpose but to confuse the post. If they are important, convert them to code. If they are not important remove them.

Comment: fine, I converted them